# Cancelling a NSURLConnection and stop downloading data

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

`NSURLConnection` has a `-cancel` method which causes further delegate messages to not be sent. However, does this also make the endpoint stop sending data to the client? I have a interface where the user can begin downloading a huge image, but also "cancel" at any moment. I don't want the device to keep receiving unwanted data as that would be a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: I think Apple is not so inefficient to let the download continue even after you cancel it. You cannot access the data anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `-cancel` closes the TCP connection, so no more data will be sent by the server.

Comment: Note: During a download the connection maintains a strong reference to the delegate. It releases that strong reference when the connection finishes loading, fails, or is canceled.